# How do I fix my broken .NET 6 installation on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core, jetbrains-rider

I have .NET 6 and .NET 7 on my Ubuntu system. When I try to execute a test in Rider it says dotnet 6 isn't installed. But it is. If I run `dotnet --list-runtimes` it shows only .NET 7.

[image: Boring console stuff]

Comment: That would be better asked on askubuntu.com. Please don't use pictures of text though, copy'n'paste the text instead. Also, read their site guidelines before posting there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have only runtime for .NET 6, but not Framework .NET 6. Building Apps and running tests needs framework too.